# Why does the inputbox make me do it twice?

Tags: vb.net, loops

I'm trying to get an in a loop to accept a value and add it to a list each time okay is pressed. For some reason, I have to add a value twice for the input to be added to the list. For example, if i enter the string "hello" in the inputbox and click okay, it doesn't add to the list, but if i do it a second time, it goes in.

Here is the code for it

```
Do Until lstCourse.Items.Count = CDbl(txtClasses.Text)
    InputBox("Enter Course Number", "Course Number")
    strCourse = InputBox("Enter Course Number", "Course Number")
    lstCourse.Items.Add(strCourse)
Loop
```

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: it would help if you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're displaying the input box twice per iteration.  The first time you're not doing anything with the return value.  The only one you need is:

```
strCourse = InputBox("Enter Course Number", "Course Number")
```

You may think what you're seeing is 2 loop iterations, but you're only seeing 1.